# Multiple client TCP/IP server - server shows that clients disconnect with the same port number

Tags: c, sockets, network-programming

Trying my hand at socket programming in C. When I connect multiple clients to the server and then disconnect them, the server shows that all clients are disconnecting on the same port.

Example: Connecting two clients and then disconnecting them.

```
./server 59001
Waiting for new connections....
Accepted new connection on 127.0.0.1:37098
Accepted new connection on 127.0.0.1:37100
Host disconnected: 127.0.0.1:37100
Host disconnected: 127.0.0.1:37100
Accepted new connection on 127.0.0.1:37102
Accepted new connection on 127.0.0.1:37106
Host disconnected: 127.0.0.1:37106
Host disconnected: 127.0.0.1:37106
```

You can see the server shows the two clients disconnecting on the same port. I'm using select for handling multiple clients, here is my server.c file:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>       /* memset */
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>    /* inet_addr */
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <unistd.h>       /* close */
#include <sys/select.h>   /* select */

#define SIZE 1024

int socket_description(int port, struct sockaddr_in server_addr);

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: ./server <port>\n\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    
    int port = atoi(argv[1]);
    struct sockaddr_in server_addr;
    struct sockaddr_in client_addr;

    //create TCP socket
    int sock_fd = socket_description(port, server_addr);

    //set up synchronous i/o for handling multiple clients
    fd_set current_sockets, ready_sockets;     //create two sets of file descriptors to store, one to track our active connection (current_sock) and the other to hold temporary (ready_sock)
    FD_ZERO(&current_sockets);                 //initialise current sockets to zero
    FD_SET(sock_fd, &current_sockets);         //adds a file descriptor to the current socket set

    //handle client data
    char buffer[SIZE];
    char *p_buffer = buffer;
    int bytes_received;

    //accept incoming connections
    fprintf(stdout, "Waiting for new connections....\n");
    socklen_t sock_len = sizeof(server_addr);


    while (1)
    {

        //copy current set of fds
        ready_sockets = current_sockets;

        int ready = select(FD_SETSIZE, &ready_sockets, NULL, NULL, NULL);
        if (ready < 0)
        {
            perror("Could not read in ready_socket file descriptors (select error)");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        

        //loop over the file descriptors that are ready to be read in
        for (int i = 0; i < FD_SETSIZE; i++)
        {
            if (FD_ISSET(i, &ready_sockets))
            {
                if (i == sock_fd)
                {
                    // this is a new connection to accept, set the new connection to the client structure
                    int client = accept(sock_fd,(struct sockaddr *)&client_addr, &sock_len);
                    if (client < 0)
                    {
                        perror("Error accepting incoming connection");
                        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                    } 
                    char const *client_ip = inet_ntoa(client_addr.sin_addr);
                    int client_port = ntohs(client_addr.sin_port);
                    fprintf(stdout, "Accepted new connection on %s:%d\n", client_ip, client_port);

                    // add the new client to the set
                    FD_SET(client, &current_sockets);
                } 
                else 
                {
                    // handle existing connection
                    if((bytes_received = recv(i,p_buffer,SIZE,0) > 0))
                    {
                        //check if the received message ends in a newline character, replace with null byte
                        if (*(p_buffer + bytes_received) == '\n')
                        {
                            *(p_buffer + bytes_received) = '\0';
                        }
                        char const *client_ip = inet_ntoa(client_addr.sin_addr);
                        fprintf(stdout, "Received message from %s: %s", client_ip, p_buffer);
                        int bytes_sent = send(i, p_buffer, bytes_received, 0);
                        if (bytes_sent < 0)
                        {
                            perror("Error receiving message");
                            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                        }  
                    }
                    // host disconnected
                    else
                    {
                        char const *client_ip = inet_ntoa(client_addr.sin_addr);
                        uint16_t client_port = ntohs(client_addr.sin_port);
                        fprintf(stdout, "Host disconnected: %s:%d\n", client_ip, client_port);
                        close(i);
                        FD_CLR(i, &current_sockets);
                    }
                }    
            }   
        }
    }

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Could be <O/T>, but what is `socket_description` doing? Passing in uninitialized `server_addr` by value is at best useless.

Comment: the function is setting up the tcp socket (creating, binding and listening) so im passing the struct for the server and the port number. The function will return the file descriptor for that master socket

Comment: `server_addr` is uninitialized. If you're using it for anything in `socket_description` you're invoking undefined behavior. If you're initializing it somehow in `socket_description`, then it can be local to that function, no need to pass it in as a parameter.

Comment: updated it, made no difference.

Comment: pretty sure your parenthesis are off here: `if((bytes_received = recv(i,p_buffer,SIZE,0) > 0))`. I think you want `if((bytes_received = recv(i,p_buffer,SIZE,0)) > 0)` instead. May not matter with the order of operations (I'd have to look them up), but the change will ensure you assign `bytes_received` first, then do the `> 0` comparison.

Comment: Also `if (*(p_buffer + bytes_received) == '\n')` is never true. (well, maybe by chance ...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed this by updating:

```
// host disconnected
else
{
   char const *client_ip = inet_ntoa(client_addr.sin_addr);
   uint16_t client_port = ntohs(client_addr.sin_port);
   fprintf(stdout, "Host disconnected: %s:%d\n", client_ip, client_port);
   close(i);
   FD_CLR(i, &current_sockets);
}
```

to the new version:

```
// host disconnected
else 
{
   getpeername(i , (struct sockaddr*)&client_addr, &client_len);          
   char const *client_ip = inet_ntoa(client_addr.sin_addr);
   uint16_t client_port = ntohs(client_addr.sin_port);
   fprintf(stdout, "Host disconnected: %s:%d\n", client_ip, client_port);
                        
   //close socket and remove client from fd_set
   close(i);
   FD_CLR(i, &current_sockets);
}
```